# Чтение запись в файл с блокировкой

Tags: c#

Есть файл с которым работает программа. Она считывает и записывает в него данные. Во время работы программы файл должен быть заблокирован на запись, но открывать на чтение его можно. Вроде все просто. Нашел такое решение

```
File.Open("Stat.csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

Дальше пробуем туда что нибудь записать

```
File.AppendAllText("Stat.csv", "test" + "\n", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
```

Выдает ошибку: процесс не может получить доступ к файла, так как файл используется другим процессом. Аналогично возникает проблема с чтением.

```
File.ReadAllText("Stat.csv");
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы делаете неправильно.

`File.Open` — это не функция, которая «открывает» файл и всё. Эта функция возвращает вам поток, который и имеет эксклюзивный доступ к файлу. Вы должны  писать в файл через этот поток.

`File.AppendAllText` ничего не знает о потоке, который возвратила функция `File.Open`. Он пытается открыть *новый* поток, но поскольку ваш файл заблокирован функцией `File.Open`, ничего не выходит.

---

Попробуйте так:

```
using (var file = File.Open("Stat.csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
using (var text = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
{
    text.WriteLine("test");
}
```

---

Если вам нужно держать файловый поток открытым, делайте как-то так:

```
private FileStream file;
```

```
// инициализация
file = File.Open("D:\\Stat.csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

```
// запись в файл
using (var text = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), 1024, leaveOpen: true))
{
    text.WriteLine("test");
}
```

Параметр `leaveOpen: true` важен!

В конце работы имеет смысл сделать `file.Dispose()`, для этого, по идее, включающий это поле класс должен бы тоже реализовать `IDisposable`.

Comment: Спасибо за теорию, подскажите тогда как правильно

Comment: @polsok: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: не работает поскольку в коде нужны множественные операции чтения записи. Используем статическую переменную 'internal static FileStream file;' Но как доходим до места записи пишет поток был недоступен для записи.

Comment: @polsok: Покажите ваш код. Вы пишете как в ответе, или нет? `internal static FileStream file` — нет, так делать не нужно.

Comment: @VladID вот смотрите тот код который вы привели в ответе работает, но надо так что бы можно было в начале программы заблокировать файл на запись и постоянно к нему обращаться. Если мы между первой и второй строкой пишем что угодно. хоть переменную объявляем. выдает ошибку внедренных оператор не может быть объявлением или оператором с идентификатором.

Comment: @polsok: Окей, снова обновил ответ.

Comment: @VladID [добавил еще один вопрос по этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705935/Дозапись-в-файл-с-блокировкой)