# Дозапись в файл с блокировкой

Tags: c#

Есть файл с которым работает программа. Она считывает и записывает в него данные. Во время работы программы файл должен быть заблокирован на запись, но открывать на чтение его можно. Использую такое решение:

```
static FileStream file = File.Open("D:\\Stat.csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // запись в файл
        using (var text = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), 1024, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            text.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
```

Все работает, но я не нашел перегрузки StreamWriter именно для **дозаписи** данных. Подскажите решение.

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос на [английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306214/append-lines-to-a-file-using-a-streamwriter). В нем предложено сразу несколько вариантов использования StreamWriter для добавления строк в уже существующий файл

Comment: @vmchar в представленной ссылке нет использования заблокированного файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае `file.Position = file.Length` перед записью.
Но вообще для этого есть более удобный метод: [`File.AppendAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx).
Файл в этом случае будет создан с блокировкой на запись и шарой на чтение:

```
return (Stream) new FileStream(path, mode, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.SequentialScan, Path.GetFileName(path), false, false, checkHost);
```

Comment: `File.AppendAllText` не подойдёт, т. к. ТС хочет держать файл заблокированным между записями. А вот `Position` — то, что надо.

Comment: @VladD Смотря для чего блокировать. :) Обычно стараются блокировать от записи, но не от чтения. :) В противном случае я бы вообще предложил открывать файл посредством [`NtCreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380(v=vs.85).aspx) c флагом `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT`. Очень дешёвая и эффективная блокировка. Ну, а дальше `Position = Length`. :)